# JS prototype ─ why 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, runtime, prototype

I have a very simple code (http://plnkr.co/edit/voHWdFfwu7TUreyjsRiU?p=preview):

```
function Fnc(){}
Fnc.prototype.fooz = function(){
    var i=0;
    Fnc.prototype.fooz = function(){
        ++i;
        console.log('i: ', i);
        return i;
    };
    Fnc.prototype.fooz();
};


window.onload=function(){
    var fa = new Fnc();
    alert(fa.fooz()); // undefined!
    alert(fa.fooz()); // 2
    alert(fa.fooz() + fa.fooz()); // 7
};
```

It outputs into console as expected, 1,2,7. But what is **unexpected**, that the first alert outputs 'undefined'.
Why?

---

UPD
Especially for i.e. *GURU*. If you set minus, plz, explain why. Thank you.

---

UPD 2. I just simply didn't set return in the first Fnc.prototype.fooz (while its redifining). Yes, quite naive error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the first `alert(fa.fooz());` The `Fnc.prototype.fooz` is not returning anything. So by default a function will return `undefined`, not all the time but in our case it will return `undefined`. And later on, the `Fnc.prototype.fooz` got assigned with new function and it is returning `i` value. That is why it is giving the expected results.

```
Fnc.prototype.fooz = function(){
    var i=0;
    Fnc.prototype.fooz = function(){
        ++i;
        console.log('i: ', i);
        return i;
    };
    Fnc.prototype.fooz();  // This is not retuning anything 
};
```

If you want to get your desired result, just change your code like below,

```
Fnc.prototype.fooz = function(){
    var i=0;
    Fnc.prototype.fooz = function(){
        ++i;
        console.log('i: ', i);
        return i;
    };
    return Fnc.prototype.fooz();  // add a return here. 
};
```

Experimenting with language will guide you to explore it. But don't modify a prototype inside a same function in your real time projects, since it would cause undesirable results.

Answer (score 2):

Your first definition of Func.prototype.fooz first redefines itself then returns undefined. Your redefinition returns something.

In JavaScript without a return most functions return undefined. The exception is functions called with new.

Answer (score 1):

> It outputs into console as expected, 1,2,7. But what is unexpected,
>   that the first alert outputs 'undefined'. But why?!

When you redefined `Fnc.prototype.fooz` inside `Fnc.prototype.fooz` it replaced the previous definition of `Fnc.prototype.fooz` which was not returning anything (means returning `undefined`).

Note that even when you redefined it the function execution `Fnc.prototype.fooz();` done first.

For example, if I add a `console.log` before function exection

```
function Fnc(){}
Fnc.prototype.fooz = function(){
    var i=0;
    Fnc.prototype.fooz = function(){
        ++i;
        console.log('i: ', i); //second print when executed first time
        return i;
    };
    console.log(Fnc.prototype.fooz); //this line will be printed first
    Fnc.prototype.fooz();
};
```

next time onwards only the console.log inside the **new definition** (that is, `console.log('i: ', i);`) is printed because previous definition has been overriden.